# SKSpriteNode can't detect collision with two bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath bodies

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I create two Object by using bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath. But when I check collision by method - (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact. It's not working.

Object 1:
    UIBezierPath *paddleLeftPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

```
[paddleLeftPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(-19,17)];
[paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20,17)];
[paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10,6)];
[paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(17,-7)];
[paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(6,-19)];
[paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(-6,-20)];
[paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(-17,-11)];
[paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(-13,6)];

[paddleLeftPath closePath];

objectRocket = [[NodeRocket alloc] initWithWithFile:@"main0.png" scale:0.5 atPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),110)];
objectRocket.name = @"Rocket";
objectRocket.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
objectRocket.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
objectRocket.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rocketCategory;
objectRocket.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  meteorCategory;
objectRocket.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  meteorCategory;
objectRocket.zPosition = 10;
objectRocket.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
[self addChild:objectRocket];
```

Object 2:
    SKNode* meteorPair = [SKNode node];
        meteorPair.position = CGPointMake( 0, 0 );
        meteorPair.zPosition = 10;

```
    NSInteger scaleValue = (arc4random() % 8) + 1;

    meteorTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"monster%d.png",(int)scaleValue]];

    [meteorTexture setFilteringMode:SKTextureFilteringNearest];

    if (pointDrop.x > self.size.width - meteorTexture.size.width/2 - 10)
    {
        pointDrop.x = self.size.width - meteorTexture.size.width/2 - 10;
    }
    else if (pointDrop.x < meteorTexture.size.width/2 + 10)
    {
        pointDrop.x = meteorTexture.size.width/2 + 10;
    }

    CGFloat x = (arc4random() % 2) + 0.5;

    CGFloat distanceToMove = self.frame.size.height - 115 - objectUFO.size.height/2;
    SKAction* moveMeteor = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-distanceToMove duration:x/100.0 * distanceToMove];
    SKAction* removeMeteor = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    moveMeteorAndRemove = [SKAction sequence:@[moveMeteor, removeMeteor]];

    SKSpriteNode* meteorObject = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:meteorTexture];
    [meteorObject setScale:0.55];
    meteorObject.position = CGPointMake(pointDrop.x, pointDrop.y - objectUFO.size.height/2 );

    UIBezierPath *paddleLeftPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [paddleLeftPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(-22,28)];
    [paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(21,28)];
    [paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(17,-30)];
    [paddleLeftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(-18,-30)];
    [paddleLeftPath closePath];
    meteorObject.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"monster%d.png",(int)scaleValue];
    meteorObject.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    meteorObject.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    meteorObject.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = meteorCategory;        
    [meteorPair addChild:meteorObject];

    [meteorPair runAction:moveMeteorAndRemove];
    meteorPair.name = @"meteor pair";

    [self addChild:meteorPair];
     meteorObject.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:paddleLeftPath.CGPath];
```

Please help me. What's I do wrong ?

Comment: see the docs, two static (edge based) bodies never generate collisions. Also using move actions bypasses the physics simulation, use applyImpulse/Force to move dynamic physics bodies.

Comment: I make the object meteorObject fall down to collision with objectRocket. But method didBeginContact not working.

Comment: I change bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath to bodyWithPolygonFromPath. and  meteorObject.physicsBody.dynamic = YES. They can collisions but method didBeginContact still not working.

Comment: did you set the collisionDelegate? Also check the category etc bitmasks, they are frequently misunderstood, they have to go both ways (ie meteor and rocket in one body, rocket and meteor in the other body - omitting just one of these bitmasks will not generate collisions).

Answer (score 0):

Have you set contactDelegate for physicsWorld of SKScene yet? Maybe you missed it then didBeginContact have never be called.
Try this on your gameScene

> self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're setting a bunch of parameters on the physics body before you assign it.

I'm new to the SKPhysics stuff, but it looks from all the examples that when you create the node, it comes with a nil/null physics body.

To be explicit.
SKSpriteNode* meteorObject = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:
...
meteorObject.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
meteorObject.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
meteorObject.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = meteorCategory;
...
meteorObject.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:

needs to be :-

SKSpriteNode* meteorObject = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:
...
meteorObject.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:
meteorObject.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
meteorObject.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
meteorObject.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = meteorCategory;
...